# customise oracle apex tabular form region

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I want to customise the tabular form region in oracle apex. I tried via editing templates, but the tabular form region was not listed in the template option . 
I want to create new region from copy of tabular form region How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What "customization" would you want to do?

As you're on Apex 5 (which version exactly?), consider switching from a Tabular Form to Interactive Grid, maybe you'll find it interesting & useful.

Comment: It is 5.0.3. Interactive grid is not available in this version. I want to customise the tabular region so that when  tbody overflows, i want to freeze the thead tag and scroll the tbody. I tried via inline css, but these css classes are referred in other places of same page, hence the code didn't worked.